# Loading an HTML file with URL parameters into a Cocoa (not iPhone) WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, url, webview

I'm using the following to load an HTML file into a WebView in my Mac OSX app:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[[WebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

This works fine ... but what I need to do is read that same file with some URL parameters attached to it (say `foo.html?var=bar`), which some JavaScript will then use for output. I tried using `URLByAppendingPathExtension:` on fileURL, but no dice...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that URLs created using the `fileURLWithPath:` method do not support query strings, as generally a query string makes no sense for a URL referencing a file on disk.

I would highly recommend you run a local web server and use `http://` scheme URLs if you want to pass URL parameters to code in a web page. Relying on the `WebView` supporting query strings on `file://` URLs is fragile, in my opinion.

That said, you can construct the URL using the `URLWithString:` method like this and it will work:

```
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/you/Desktop/foo.html?bar=foobar"];
```

In your case you'd probably do something like:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost%@?var=%@", filePath, @"bar"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on the second line. Fixed. That's what happens when you write code in the browser!

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. Try logging `URLString`. What do you get?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", URLString);` on the line after `URLString` is declared.

Comment: The log shows the URL as I'd like it, parameter and all ... but nothing but a blank page is loaded...

Comment: Perhaps I'm making an error elsewhere. The full chunk of code I'm using is: `            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"];
            NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost%@?var=%@",filePath,@"bar"];
            //NSLog(URLString);
            NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
            [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];`

Comment: What happens if you paste the exact string that is logged into Safari's address bar?

Comment: Are you actually loading the URL? You should still have the `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[[WebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];` lines in your code.

Comment: I am ... it's in that jumble of code four comments up that didn't format correctly...

Comment: Well, I'd still prefer a more proper way of doing this, but I've just changed it back to the previous version, where it now loads in an HTML file, `redirect.html`, that contains nothing but a `<META>` element that refreshes to the URL `foo.html?var=bar` after 0 seconds. It's hack-y, but it's working nicely, so it'll have to do for now...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = ...
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingFormat:@"?var=%@", @"bar"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
...
```